# Colorbox is issuing duplicate AJAX requests from IE

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Colorbox is issuing duplicate AJAX requests from IE while same works just fine for Firefox. Is it a browser bug or it's a bug with Colorbox itself?

I am using the code like this

```
$(".iframe").colorbox(href:"www.google.com",speed:0,IFrame:true,fastIframe:false,Open:true,OverlayClose:false)
```

Any sugggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code syntactically is wrong, you are passing properies but there is no object, also options are camelCased, properties are case-sensitive, read the documentation and use the correct properties.

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({
    href: "www.google.com",
    speed: 0,
    iframe: true,
    fastIframe: false,
    open: true,
    overlayClose: false
});
```